# How to get height or width of content and layout in Typst as a length type?

Tags: typst

How to get widths of content and layout as a number (`length` type in Typst).

---

What I tried is to use `layout()` and `measure()` as suggested by [Typst doc](https://typst.app/docs/reference/layout/measure/). Using these functions, I can show the width, for example `453.54pt`, on the pdf file, but the data type of `453.54pt` is `content`, and I cannot convert it to `length` type.

More specifically, I tried the following code:

```
#let layoutwidth = layout(size => {return size.width})
#let textwidthof(body) = context { return measure(body).width} // a function
#let atextwidth = textwidthof[Hello World]
```

Although we can print the two widths `layoutwidth` and `atextwidth` on the pdf file, it is of type `content`, not `length`. I also tried to convert it to string `str()` and then `eval()`, but it does not work! Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been facing the exact same problem today, and finally found that it's due to the `context`.

In the [measure](https://typst.app/docs/reference/layout/measure/) doc page they say it has to be used in a given [context](https://typst.app/docs/reference/context/) because it depends on where it is in the document.

The thing is you have to be in a context to access the fields of `width` and `height` :

```
#let authors = ("John One", "John Two", "John Three")
#let org = "University"

#let auths = text(style: "italic")[#authors.join(", ")]

#context {
    let authsize = measure(auths).width
    let orgsize = measure(org).width
    set page(
        footer: [
            #text(size: 11pt)[#auths] #h(100% -authsize -orgsize -1pt) #text(style: "italic")[#org]
        ]
    )
}
```

However this would not work because the variable only exist in the `context` :

```
#context {
    let authsize = measure(auths).width
    let orgsize = measure(org).width
}

#set page(
    footer: [
        #text(size: 11pt)[#auths] #h(100% -authsize -orgsize -1pt) #text(style: "italic")[#org]
    ]
)
```

And the following is what returns a content that we can't use, I'm not sure of the reason but I would guess that the content type comes from the context keyword :

```
#let authsize = context measure(auths).width
#let orgsize = context measure(org).width

#set page(
    footer: [
        #text(size: 11pt)[#auths] #h(100% -authsize -orgsize -1pt) #text(style: "italic")[#org]
    ]
)
```

Edit :
If the goal is to spread text across the page, it's better to use `fr` instead of `context` and `measure`.

```
footer: [
    #text(size: 11pt)[#auths] #h(1fr) #text(style: "italic")[#org]
]
```